# How do I make a running and working batch file from a pre-made batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

So I am trying to make a batch file from a pre-made batch file and I don't know how to got to the next line in the file without ruining it and it just saying what I want the command to do. This is what I have so far.

```
@echo off

:batch
cd C:\
cd Users
cd User1
cd Desktop
cd test10
type nul > test10.bat
echo Ipconfig /all
```

After the `Ipconfig /all` it runs the command like normal but if I tried to do this for example

```
@echo off

:batch
cd C:\
cd Users
cd User1
cd Desktop
cd test10
type nul > test10.bat
echo Ipconfig /all > test10.bat
echo PAUSE > test10.bat
```

If I did that it would just say "PAUSE"

This is the current code for the batch file I am using to make the second one

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

So can someone please help me with this??

Comment: If you're not proficient in batch, why are you trying to learn it now? Yourf time is better spent learing PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

**You should use `>>` instead of `>`**

When using `>` to write in a file, you will overwrite all the content of the file.

When using `>>` , you will append data to the existing file.

Your code should look like something like that :

```
@echo off

:batch
cd C:\
cd Users
cd User1
cd Desktop
cd test10
type nul > test10.bat
echo Ipconfig /all > test10.bat
echo PAUSE >> test10.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cd` command must contain `/D`, this means, go to `/D`rive...

Without the use of the `/D` flag in `cd` command, the cmd.exe (command line interpreter) will not go to the `C:` drive, if the `cd` is not going, it may not run in error when the bat is running on the same drive (`C:`), but when your bat is running on a drive other than `C:`, your bat `Test10.bat` will be created in the current/running folder, instead of the desired/pointed folder.

Assuming there is no `Users\User1\Desktop\test10` folder in the folder where the bat is running, and all cd command will results in errors...

```
I:\>cd C:\

I:\>cd Users
The system cannot find the path specified.

I:\>cd User1
The system cannot find the path specified.

I:\>cd Desktop
The system cannot find the path specified.

I:\>cd test10
The system cannot find the path specified.

I:\>
```

You can do this using one more precisely/simple way...

```
@echo off

:batch
cd /d "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test10\" && (
echo Ipconfig /all 
echo PAUSE ) >.\test10.bat
```

- You can also replace:
  **`cd /d C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test10\ ... >test10.bat`**
  To:
  **`> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test10\test10.bat`"**:

```
@echo off

:batch
> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test10\test10.bat" (
    echo\ Ipconfig /all
    echo\ PAUSE 
   )
```

---

**Obs.:1** But keep in mind that some characters may require additional escaping to be necessary for some commands, redirectors, operators, etc...

`^| ^| ^| ^& ^&^& ^> ^>^> ^< ^<^< %% ^( ^)`

```
echo timeout 3 >nul
→ echo timeout 3 ^>nul 

echo cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test10\test10.bat" 2>nul || pause
→ echo cd /d "%%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop\test10\test10.bat" 2^>nul ^|^| pause

echo cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test10\test10.bat" 2>nul && ( 
→  echo cd /d "%%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop\test10\test10.bat" 2^>nul ^&^& ^( 

echo Ipconfig /all 2>nul  || echo\ error Ipconfig command... 
→ echo Ipconfig /all 2^>nul ^|^| echo\ error Ipconfig command...
```

---

**Obs.:2** There is another way to generate at runtime, a bat without escaping, without expanding variable values, and without using echo : see this answer

### **[Echo Variables Without Getting the Data of The Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581426/echo-variables-without-getting-the-data-of-the-variables-in/62598988#62598988)**

#### Additional Resources:

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`CD /D /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)
- Windows Variables :

  - [Environment](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)